# Formulário ModelForm dinâmico - Django

Tags: javascript, django, formulário

Olá! Estou utilizando ModelForm do django 2.2, e preciso deixar o formulário dinâmico. O campo "Quantidade de parcelas" só deve aparecer quando o Método de pagamento for crédito.

[image]

A princípio tentei fazer com JS:

```
function exibir_ocultar(){
var valor = $("#id_metodo_de_pagamento").val();

if(valor == 'credito'){
     $("#id_quantidade_de_parcelas").show();

 } else {
     $("#id_quantidade_de_parcelas").hide();
 } };
```

Me deparei com o problema de não conseguir editar o select para chamar a função JS, já que o próprio Django gera o formulário. Segue o código utilizado para gerar o formulário:

```
           {% bootstrap_messages %}
            <form action="{% url 'cadastro' %}" method="POST" class="form" autocomplete="off" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% bootstrap_form form %}
                {% buttons %}
                    <button type="submit" href="{% url 'index' %}" class= "btn btn-success">Salvar </button>
                    <button type="submit" href="{% url 'index' %}" name="exit" value="True" class= "btn btn-dark">Salvar e fechar </button>                                
               {% endbuttons %}
            </form>
```

Qual a melhor forma de realizar essa ação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então rapaziada, pra quem está com a mesma dúvida e não quer depender desses **fracassados** em sua vida fora de fórumzinho que marcam a pergunta como "nenhum esforço", segue o que utilizei para aplicar essa ideia em meu projeto de **estudo** (ESTUDO, logo significa que não tenho muita noção de como ou o quê pesquisar e explicar minhas dúvidas, rsrs)

No django existem os widgets, o que torna possível inserir elementos de entrada HTML. Fui até o arquivo "forms.py" do projeto, e dentro da classe Meta, onde é especificado os fields do formulário, conseguimos definir os elementos HTML a partir de um dicionário em python.

```
from django import forms
from .models import Compra

class CompraModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Compra
    fields = ['nome_da_compra', 'preco', 'data_da_compra', 'local_da_compra', 'metodo_de_pagamento', 'quantidade_de_parcelas']
    widgets  =  { 'metodo_de_pagamento': forms.Select(attrs = {'onchange' : "exibir_ocultar();"}) }
```

Após isso, a ideia de exibir e ocultar os campos funciona perfeitamente. Utilizei o script JS dentro da pasta static e importei ele pro meu HTML através da tag script. Abraço!